# Applying over 200 textures to a single model

Tags: texturing, shaders

I downloaded a bus model from a website that came with a fbx file and a folder containing 226 png texture files. I just don't know how to apply all those texture files to model. The screenshot shows the shading editor with a purple coloured bus (indicating that textures have not yet been applied I guess). On the left side are some of the listed textures.  [image]

Comment: Hello :). The purple might just mean the textures weren't *found*, Go *File > External Data > Find missing files* and Blender should load them. If not, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: When I did that it didn't find it. I manually directed Blender to the correct folder containing those texture files. However, the "find missing files" feature / procedure only allows me to select one file at a time. There must be a way where all those textures are loaded quickly/instantly to model as the author of this creation intended.

Comment: Hey :). It targets a folder, not a specific file. If Blender isn't missing any files (*External Data > Report missing files*), the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: ah yes you are right. It apparently found a bunch of missing files.

Comment: If you happen to have a cgtrader account, here is the link of the model file I downloaded if you have time to see it for yourself. (https://www.cgtrader.com/items/2263056/download-page) Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Hello again :). I checked the model, but couldn't make it import properly. I'd suggest trying out a different one - you'd need to find and connect all the textures manually which is a helluva lot of work for such a badly prepared model. Good luck :)

Comment: Yeah .. that is what I wanted to avoid .. mulitple connections (226 to be exact) of texture nodes. I just have a feeling that there must be an easier and faster way. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: Well, the import usually works fine, but this model wasn't prepared very well. Some of the provided textures are renamed, others are missing altogether. Seriously, pick a different model :).